# PHP Form not updating

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm totally stuck on a problem. I'm practicing MySQL data inserts from php, but I am unable to get it working. I am totally new when it comes to php. With MySQL and HTML, I did a few courses on it, so you can say I'm a beginner. This is part three of the example, the first example you have to list all the animals in the table, that part I got working, then the second part is where I have to use a named parameters to extract specific animal types, and it also works fine. Now I'm stuck with the last one inserting data. I have a simple form with animal name and animal type as text boxes, when I click on submit the updated row must auto update in example one and show in the table, but when I click on submit, nothing happens, nothing is inserted into the database, but when I refresh the page or click submit again, then only do I see the updated data. And when fill in data in the two text fields after I clicked refresh or submit, blank data is inserted into the database.

```
<?php

$db = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals';                    
$username = 'root';                                         
$password = '';

$animal_type   = $_POST[animal_type];
$animal_name   = $_POST[animal_name];

$query = "INSERT INTO animals
          (animal_type, animal_name)
          VALUES
          ('$animal_type', '$animal_name')";
$animal = $db->prepare($query);                                 
$animal->bindValue(':animal_id', $animal_id);
$animal->execute();
$animals = $animal->fetchAll();                                 
$animal->closeCursor();                                         
?>

<form action="example3.php" method="post">
Animal Name: <input type="text" name="animal_name"><br>
Animal Type: <input type="text" name="animal_type"><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
JasonK

**Update**

So this is what it looks like when completed, but you see those blank entries is what happens when I fill in animal type and animal name and click submit - it just leaves the fields blank, I checked in the database, it does the insert when I click submit. I deduced that whenever I click submit or do a page refresh, it runs the whole code again that is where the blank entries comes from.

This is what my whole code look like.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Example1/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<?php include 'menu.inc'; 

$db = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animal';
$username = 'jason';
$password = '';                         

try {                                                           
$db = new PDO($db, $username, $password);                   
echo 'Connection successful';                               
echo '<br />';
}
catch(PDOException $e)                                          
{
echo 'Connection failed' . $e->getMessage();                
}

$query = 'SELECT animal_type, animal_name                       
FROM animals';                                      

$animal = $db->query($query);                                   
$animal->execute();                                             
$animals = $animal->fetchAll();                                 
$animal->closeCursor();                                         
echo "<br>";
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Animal Type</th>

<th>Animal Name</th>
</tr>                                   
<?php foreach ($animals as $animal) { ?>                        
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $animal['animal_type']; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $animal['animal_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>                                              
</table>
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Example2/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<?php

$animal_type = "leopard";

$query = 'SELECT *                      
FROM animals
WHERE animal_type = :animal_type';

$animal = $db->prepare($query);                                 
$animal->bindValue(':animal_type', $animal_type);
$animal->execute();
$animals = $animal->fetchAll();                                 
$animal->closeCursor();
?>

<p>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Animal Type</th>

<th>Animal Name</th>
</tr>                                   
<?php foreach ($animals as $animal) { ?>                        
<tr> 
<td><?php echo $animal['animal_type']; ?></td>

<td><?php echo $animal['animal_name']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>

</table>

</p>


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Example3/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<?php

$db = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals';                    
$username = 'jason';                                         
$password = '';

$animal_type   = $_POST['animal_type'];
$animal_name   = $_POST['animal_name'];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals', $username, $password);

$query = "INSERT INTO animals
SET animal_type = :animal_type,
animal_name = :animal_name";
$animal = $db->prepare($query);                                 
$animal->bindParam(':animal_type', $animal_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$animal->bindParam(':animal_name', $animal_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$animal->execute();                             
?>

<form action="example3.php" method="post">
Animal Name: <input type="text" name="animal_name"><br>
Animal Type: <input type="text" name="animal_type"><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: completed example scenario]

Comment: Why are you binding values when you haven't used the values in your insert query? Which I may add, you should be using `:value` as the insert values rather than the variable:|

Comment: Can you tell us what is the output or error of above code

Comment: please first decide what you have to an insert or an update?
in question, you are saying that you want to update but in a code, you are inserting the data.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I am inserting into a mysql database from the form. Then what must happen is when I click submit it has to update the table that I create in example 2

Answer (score 1):

To get value from super_globals like (`$_POST`,`$_REQUEST`,`$_GET`) you have to pass index as string

change

```
$animal_type   = $_POST[animal_type];
$animal_name   = $_POST[animal_name];
```

to

```
$animal_type   = $_POST["animal_type"];
$animal_name   = $_POST["animal_name"];
```

And remove un-necessary binding value

```
$animal->bindValue(':animal_id', $animal_id); //remove this
```

**Also hope you have created database connection and store it in `$db`**

Your insert query is also vulnerable to SQL Injections. Use bind param to insert value

```
$query = "INSERT INTO animals
          (animal_type, animal_name)
          VALUES
          (:animal_type, :animal_name)";
$animal = $db->prepare($query);                                 
$animal->bindParam(':animal_type', $animal_type);
$animal->bindParam(':animal_name', $animal_name);
$animal->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$db = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals';                    
$username = 'root';                                         
$password = '';

$animal_type   = $_POST['animal_type'];
$animal_name   = $_POST['animal_name'];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals', $username, "");

$query = "INSERT INTO animals
          SET animal_type = :animal_type,
          animal_name = :animal_name";
$animal = $db->prepare($query);                                 
$animal->bindParam(':animal_type', $animal_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$animal->bindParam(':animal_name', $animal_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$animal->execute();                             
?>

<form action="example3.php" method="post">
Animal Name: <input type="text" name="animal_name"><br>
Animal Type: <input type="text" name="animal_type"><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This is almost correct. Was just about to upvote it. Check your insert syntax. It should be VALUES not SET and please add explanations as OP is a beginner

Comment: I corrected, I did not pay too much attention to everything :)

Comment: Syntax for insert is INSERT INTO table(col,col)VALUES(val,val)

Comment: Why not SET?
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html
In my opinion, it is much simpler and more transparent than VALUE. Thx for -1 :)

Comment: Interesting. I'll look into that.i never knew that.  And I didn't down vote you. Now I'm upvoting it +1 :). This should be the accepted answer then

Comment: INSERT INTO .... SET also works in MySQL @Akintunde read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html ... check the second insert syntax... it's only not ANSI compliant you can't probably use INSERT INTO ... SET for other databases so it's adviceable to use INSERT INTO .... VALUES

Answer (score 0):

where do you create the database? the only thing i see is a string named `$db` I think you forgot to create a PDO object like this 
`$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals', $username, "");`
otherwise ist try's to a prepare statement to a string

and array indexes must be a string like this  `$_POST["animal_type"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //check wheter form submit or not
    $db = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=animals';                    
    $username = 'root';                                         
    $password = '';

    $animal_type   = $_POST['animal_type'];
    $animal_name   = $_POST['animal_name'];

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO animals
              (animal_type, animal_name) VALUES (?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $animal_type, $animal_name);
    $stmt->execute();

}                                        
?>

<form  method="post">
Animal Name: <input type="text" name="animal_name"><br>
Animal Type: <input type="text" name="animal_type"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> // change this markup input
</form>
```

Refer this link for more php and mysql tutoral https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp